# Show subgroups of an abelian group isomorphic to each other

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am working on this problem and got stuck:

Let $G$ be a group with three normal subgroups $N_1, N_2, N_3$. Suppose whenever $i$ and $j$ are distinct in $\{1,2,3\}$, $G = N_i N_j$, and $N_i \cap N_j = \{e\}$.

Show that $N_1 \simeq N_2 \simeq  N_3$.

I have shown that $G$ is in fact abelian, hence $N_i$'s are abelian subgroups. In order to show that they are isomorphic to each other, i tried to define an isomorphism between $N_i$ and $N_j$ but I can't come to the conclusion. Is my approach not feasible? Should I try another way?

Comment: See this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294487/n-1-n-2-n-3-unlhd-g-n-i-cap-n-j-e-g-n-in-j-want-to-show-that-g-is?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Let me give a short answer in the case where the $N_i$ (and so $G$) are *finite*.

Your assumptions imply that $G$ is the [internal direct product](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Internal_direct_product) of any of the two subgroups, namely $$G \simeq N_1 \times N_2 \simeq N_1 \times N_3 \simeq N_2 \times N_3.$$

As a consequence of Krull-Schmidt theorem, [cancellation laws holds for finite factors in direct product of groups](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2317133) and so we obtain $$N_1 \simeq N_2 \simeq N_3.$$